# Subscribing to multiple publishers through MQTT broker using NodeMCU board

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, nodemcu

I have several questions about this topic so I will post them here altogether, otherwise I have to make separate post about separate questions.
The scenario is that I have NodeMCU board which I will be using to receive multiple messages from multiple publishers through a MQTT broker(MQTT box). The following are the queries whose clarification I need, I still haven't implemented yet, I am just forming the logic. Lets say I will be receiving messages from 4 NodeMCU board continuously though MQTT broker, which I will then send to server for storing, the problem is

- Will the message of 1 publisher override the message of another publisher before I can store them in server?
- The messages that comes from MQTT broker, are they stored in ROM or RAM of NodeMCU board?
- Can a MQTT broker send data from 2 publishers concurrently to the same NodeMCU board?

The post is a hot mess, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answers:

- If 2 publishers publish on the same topic then messages will be delivered to any subscribers to that topic in the order they are published. So Publisher 1's message will arrive, then Publisher 2's message. Since messages are received sequentially you should not loose a message because it is interrupted by the next message.
- Arriving messages will be in RAM when they are delivered
- Brokers just deliver messages to any client subscribed to a topic, the client will not even know that there are multiple publishers (there is no publisher specific information in a MQTT message), just that it receives multiple messages on that specific topic

Comment: What if 2 publishers publish on 2 different topic? and 1 nodemcu board is subscribed to those 2 topics, what will happen in that scenario?

Comment: They are still delivered sequentially by the broker

Comment: If two different publishers, that are running as two separate processes (even if on the same machine), you cannot know in what order the messages will be received by the dispatcher (even if they are emitted "at the same time"). So the only nuance to what you said is that order is not guaranteed when the publishers are unsynchronized parallel processes.

Comment: They will be delivered in the order they are received by the broker

Comment: so from what i understand is that there are no scenario of data loss, which means to preserve memory, all i hav to do is to call some sort of clear function to clear the RAM after the last payload is delivered. Correct?

Comment: Anyways, thank you for the replies, I dnt see any option for up voting Oliver's answer.. I have accepted harlib's answer as the solution. Thank you all. Will reply to this post after i implement the logic.